# Highlight table cell on touch down inside?

Tags: xamarin, tableview

The default behavior in a Xamarin `Tableview` is to highlight the cell someone selects on touch up inside. The Tasky example app shows this behavior.

The standard iOS behavior is to highlight the cell on touch down inside, then allow the user to scroll (un-highlights cell). Then the cell is selected when you touch up inside. Mail is a good example of this.

We're racking our brains on this one. This behavior seems like it should be built in. We tried to build it ourselves with gestures but it gets a bit tricky.

This seems like a common problem that has already been solved, so we don't want to re-invent the wheel. Rdio even does it the 'right' way :).